# Gitlab runner auto-scale in Spot instance with IAM ROLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-machine

I am following this `gitlab` [article](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws/) on autoscaling gitlab runner on AWS spot instances.

I have a `terraform` code I need to execute and since these spot instances don't have an `IAM role` attached to them (since they are automatically spinning up by the runner) it gives me this pretty obvious error:

```
 Error creating VPC: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message
```

And this is my gitlab-runner `config.toml`, In here, **where I can define the IAM role to be attached when the spot instance is spinning up** ?

```
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 1
    IdleTime = 1800
    MaxBuilds = 3
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "shared-gitlab-runner-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-access-key=<ommited>",
      "amazonec2-secret-key=<ommited>",
      "amazonec2-region=us-east-2",
      "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-b76528dc",
      "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-d274q29e",
      "amazonec2-zone=c",
      "amazonec2-use-private-address=true",
      "amazonec2-tags=gitlab-aws-autoscaler,gitlab,true,gitlab-runner-autoscale,true",
      "amazonec2-security-group=ssh",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=t2.medium",
      "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true",
      "amazonec2-spot-price=0.07",
      "amazonec2-block-duration-minutes=60"
    ]
```

Comment: If the spot instances use the permissions associated to the user of the access and secret key, then there is no need for an IAM role.

Comment: Eventhough the spot instance uses access and secret keys, it should have permissions to carry out certain tasks right? for that, don't we use the IAM ROLE?

Comment: You attach IAM policy with the required permissions on the IAM User associated with the access and secret keys. You may refer to the AWS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage-attach-detach.html#add-policies-console